# Python is returning an error but the code is ok

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've written a small code of finding the calendar month, but python returns error

```
# First import the calendar module

import calendar

# ask of month and year

yy = int(input("Enter year: "))
mm = int(input("Enter month: "))

# display the calendar

print(calendar.month(yy, mm))
```

Now, when I run this code in kali linux using "python3 calendar.py". It returns this error..

```
python3 calendar.py
Enter year: 1989
Enter month: 8
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "calendar.py", line 3, in <module>
    import calendar
  File "/root/calendar.py", line 12, in <module>
    print(calendar.month(yy, mm))
AttributeError: module 'calendar' has no attribute 'month'
```

And when I run this in some online python interpreter, it works A OK.

Comment: You named your script `calendar.py`, change the name

Answer (score 1):

Because you named the Python script "calendar.py". It is importing the current file instead of the real module. Change the name and it will work.